# Creating an XML document with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

In all the examples and tutorials I have seen of BeautifulSoup, an HTML/XML document is passed and a soup object is returned which can then be used to modify the document. However, how can I use BeautifulSoup to create a HTML/XML document from scratch? In other words, I have data that I would like to put in an XML file, but the XML file does not exist yet and I would like to build it from scratch. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create an empty `BeautifulSoup()` object:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup()
```

and start adding elements:

```
soup.append(soup.new_tag("a", href="http://www.example.com"))
```

For XML you could start out with a XML header by using the `xml` tree builder:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(features='xml')
```

This requires lxml to be installed first. This sets the `.is_xml` flag on the `BeautifulSoup` object (which can also be set manually).

Comment: What about for XML documents? Will the same code work or will I need to specify different parser when creating BeautifulSoup object?