# Python Google Web Crawler

Tags: python, xml, search, web-crawler

I am working on a project that needs to do a search on the internet (i.e. stack overflow). Retrieve all relevant results (URL, text, images paths) from the crawler from the search to an XML file. I am building it with python. Does anyone have any suggestion as to how i should approach this problem? I don't want to scan through the entire web, just top relevant results (stackoverflow, 10/08/2013, python as an example)

Comment: "I don't want to scan through the entire web ..."-do you mean website?

Answer (score 0):

for stackoverflow you can use the api directly

for example:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?fromdate=1381190400&todate=1381276800&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow

see https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2013-10-08&todate=2013-10-09&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&filter=default&site=stackoverflow

you can't making more  30 requests a second see http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: stackoverflow was just an example i was acutally thinking about doing a search through google for data.

Comment: actually the term of service of google forbid automatic request

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use BeautifulSoup. And check out this thread, it sounds like it's what you need. [Creating an XML document with BeautifulSoup: StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305533/creating-an-xml-document-with-beautifulsoup)

As for downloading and using BeautifulSoup, the site is [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

It's pretty simple to use.
Hope this helps.